# SSH tunneling to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, ssh, tunneling

I need to connect sqldeveloper to a database server port at 1521, but the db server is behind a firewall and allows only SSH connections. how can i utilize the ssh tunneling to connect sqldeveloper to the server

scenario:
local machine ip(windows 7)   : 10.1.2.xxx
oracle database server ip(solaris) : 10.1.100.xxx

connections from local ip to database is restricted to SSH only and i have ssh access to the database server
can anyone tell how to create the ssh tunnel in this case.

similar entry:
[How can I connect to Oracle Database 11g server through ssh tunnel chain (double tunnel, server in company network)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653788/how-can-i-connect-to-oracle-database-11g-server-through-ssh-tunnel-chain-double)

Comment: Why doesn't the 'similar entry' you pointed to apply? The accepted answer seems to be doing exactly what you want?

Comment: tried the solution, but sqldeveloper throwing error while connecting as connection refused/error connecting to database

Comment: then you're doing something slightly wrong, but impossible to guess what. If you have an SSH connection to the DB server and have a tunnel over it, so you have a listening port on localhost on your PC, then SQL Developer connects to that. If it's defined right it will connect to the real listener on the DB server. Without knowing how you defined the tunnel and how you're now connecting from SQL Developer it's kind of hard to know what's wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

use PuTTY for tunneling: SSH -> Tunnels -> Add new forwarded port -> source port: 1521 -> destination: 10.1.100.xxx:1521 -> add

ssh into server

connect from local machine to localhost:1521

Comment: done the forwarding using putty, while doing netstat on local machine, listening is shown on 1521 port with ip address 127.0.0.1
is there any mapping to be done on the dbserver also for tunneling?